# un_directed ids in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Okay, say i have two data frames which is seen as below:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = [{'time': '2016-11-01 17:38:25', 
        'id1': '49466',
        'id2': '6989', 
        'amount': '23.74'}]

df2 = [{'time': '2016-11-01 17:49:26', 
        'id1': '6989',
        'id2': '49466', 
        'amount': '25.32'}]
```

I then create the data frames.

```
b_p = pd.DataFrame(df1)

s_p = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Within these frames I get:

```
b_p: 

amount  id1 id2 time
0   23.74   49466   6989    2016-11-01 17:38:25

s_p:

amount  id1 id2 time
0   25.32   6989    49466   2016-11-01 17:49:26
```

As you can see in `id1` and `id2` respectfully, the b_p data frame show a connection but in the second dataframe it shows a connection just in reverse order. My question is, is there a way to make it where if an id is connected to another id that it upholds some commutative property in the second dataframe? Like can i store this somewhere and make sure it spots it in a second data frame? I already know that the two ids have been used because the first dataframe is a past data set, so when i look at the present data set I already know these users have had some sort of connection before. First time user, long time reader. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd do two things:

- I'd save in both dataframes the order of the ids.  True, if `id1` is less than `id2`, False otherwise.
- Then id save in different columns `['i1', 'i2']`, the sorted ids.

This way, you can always compare without regard to order or with it.

```
b_p['direction'] = b_p.id1.lt(b_p.id2)
b_p = b_p.join(
    pd.DataFrame(np.sort(b_p[['id1', 'id2']].values, 1), b_p.index, ['i1', 'i2'])
)
b_p
```

[image]

```
s_p['direction'] = s_p.id1.lt(s_p.id2)

s_p = s_p.join(
    pd.DataFrame(np.sort(s_p[['id1', 'id2']].values, 1), s_p.index, ['i1', 'i2'])
)
s_p
```

[image]

---

***experiment***

```
n = 1000000
k = 1000

d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, k, (n, 2)), columns=['i1', 'i2'])
d1.insert(2, 'v1', pd.Series(np.arange(n)).astype(str).__radd__('s'))

d2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, k, (n, 2)), columns=['i1', 'i2'])
d2.insert(2, 'x1', pd.Series(np.arange(n)).astype(str).__radd__('s'))

def track(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['direction'] = df.i1.lt(df.i2)
    df.loc[:, ['i1', 'i2']] = np.sort(df[['i1', 'i2']].values, 1)
    return df


d1 = track(d1)
d2 = track(d2)

d3 = d2.merge(d1)
d3.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 999066 entries, 0 to 999065
Data columns (total 5 columns):
i1           999066 non-null int64
i2           999066 non-null int64
x1           999066 non-null object
direction    999066 non-null bool
v1           999066 non-null object
dtypes: bool(1), int64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 39.1+ MB
```

[image]

Comment: I really like this idea. If the data frame's shape was lets say (3.5 mill, 4) would this take a long time to use boolean operators and sorting a new index. When i did an inner join i found that iterating through a large dataset like 3.5 million can be very problematic. I really really like this idea though! I'm going to give this baby a shot! Thanks!